# Best way of handling large JSON data import in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've set up a fairly simple Django web app on Google Cloud to handle POSTed API calls that import JSON data into my database. I currently use the standard DRF models to handle serialization as well as validation. However, I've noticed some of the POSTs with larger JSONs timeout after 60 seconds on upload. I am guessing I can just increase the timeout settings on the Google Cloud instance, but was wondering from the perspective of Django what the best step would be. This is a learning project, as I'm new to Django, so I had several ideas on how to proceed. Was wondering if anyone had advice on this topic.

1. Use the Django FileUpload parser. However, I'm not sure this would avoid the timeout issue, and I would have to write my own custom file validation script.
2. Some sort of asynchronous processing where the file is uploaded, some ID is returned to the user which can used with a different endpoint to see when the upload has been processed and validated successfully. The downside of this is to my knowledge Django has no about-the-box solution for async support yet so it might be out-of-scope for a relative beginner.
3. Switch to using Flask. If I'm largely learning on my own should I even be using Django? I imagine Flask might be more efficient for handling large amounts of data but I don't know. So far my current solution has worked well, but if its best to switch I'd rather do that sooner than later.

Comment: Do you use Django models to interact with database in your project or just drf serializers for your json?

Comment: Have you tried to check when happens the delay? when you extract the data or when you store it in your database? you can control and limit the size of the data returned with DRF pagination, that could be an option

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov Yes, I'm using the standard Django models to control structure of the JSON being accepted.

Comment: @ManuelCarrero I'm less worried about the data returned as opposed to the data that is being posted so pagination wouldn't help. I imagine the delay comes from the upload/validation of the large JSON.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? specifically in the way you are doing the request to the source data and then, when you serialization it